# Select 20 first rows per each entry

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I've got a large dataset (millions of records) with this structure:

```
id | ident1  |  ident2  
1    A000001    B000001 
2    A000001    B000002
................

99   A000001    B000099
.........
337  A000002    B000037
338  A000002    B000043
```

In other words, for each [ident1], I have a high number of entries in [ident2]. I'd like to be able to select only 20 of these entries (of all of them, if there's less than 20).

Order is not important: so if a given ident1 has 100 matching [ident2],  I'd like either the first 20 entries, or 20 random ones, it doesn't matter.

Thanks in advance,      p.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ident1) %>%
   slice(1:20)
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, head(.SD,20), by=ident1]
```

If you need a sample

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[sample(.N,20, replace=FALSE)], by=ident1]$V1]
```

If some of the groups have less than `20` rows to `sample`

```
setDT(df)[,if(.N < 20) .SD else .SD[sample(.N,20, replace=FALSE)], by=group]
```

Comment: I was writing exactly the same thing but using `sample_n(20)` instead of `slice` :)

Comment: @DavidePassaretti  I think you can post it as the OP wants either the first or random samples.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. "dplyr" is not available in my version. I've installed "plyr", but it doesn't recognize %>% when manipulating the data frame...  
setDT seems to do the trick, though (still no idea how, but I'll find out!). Thanks

Comment: @user3310782  It is better to upgrade your version to the new one (`R.3.1.2`).  `setDT` converts the dataframe to `data.table`

Answer (score 3):

As the @akrun answer, I use `dplyr`, but in my case you are selecting observations randomly.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ident1) %>%
  sample_n(20)
```

or:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ident1) %>%
  sample_frac(.2) # randomly select the 20 % from each group
```

Using `plyr`:

#### random selection of observations:

```
ddply(df, .(ident1), function(x, howmany) {

    x[sample(seq_len(nrow(x)), howmany), ]

}, howmany = 20)
```

#### selecting the first 20 obs:

```
ddply(df, .(ident1), head, 20)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you know the equivalent in plyr (dplyr not available for download anymore, I think)? thnx

Comment: @beginneR indeed it's very strange that he cannot download such a package.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option to get the first 20 rows per `ident1`, though not as efficient as data.table or dplyr, would be:

```
df[ave(seq_along(df$ident1), df$ident1, FUN = seq_along) <= 20, ]
```